# FirebaseUI login widget not working in Angular 8 SPA after logout

Tags: angular, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to get FirebaseUI work in Angular 8 SPA app. However, the FirebaseUI login widget is NOT displayed after sign out.

I have 2 Angular components and 1 service:

- In the **FrontpageComponent** I have integrated FirebaseUI login
  widget.
- In the **UserProfileComponent** I have a sign out button.
- In the **AuthenticationService** I have implemented
  **firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged** to track changes to the auth state and handle routing accordingly.

I have uploaded the solution to Github: https://github.com/MIT-bits/single-page-app

To make it work:

1. Clone/download from GitHub
2. Unzip and navigate to solution folder
3. Run npm install (to install all node_modules)
4. Run ng serve -o (to build and run solution in browser)

Screendumps:

[Step 1 - Frontpage WITH FirebaseUI login widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ellHm.png)

[Step 2 - User is logged in](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tG1hK.png)

[Step 3 - User is logged out showing frontpage WITHOUT FirebaseUI widget](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDGc0.png)

I think the problem is due to line 62 in **FrontpageComponent**:

```
this.ui.start('#firebaseui-auth-container', firebaseUIConfig);
```

Can someone see what I am doing wrong or missing?

Any input is valuable...

****** UPDATE *******

If I reload the page before clicking "Sign out" button, the FirebaseUI widget works/is shown e.g.

```
signOut(){
    location.reload(); //HACK - and not super awesome!!!

    firebase.auth().signOut();
  }
```

Comment: Visiting the frontpage after signing out redirects me to https://www.accountchooser.com/redirect.html#localhost:4200

Comment: Can you deploy the code so we don't have to go through cloning / installing?

Comment: @Stratubas - it turns out there is a setting to disable accountchooser.com. I have disabled it in the variable firebaseUIConfig inside FrontpageComponent.

Comment: Ah, I see. Take a look at https://github.com/anthonynahas/ngx-auth-firebaseui it has marked "Sign out" as unavailable for firebaseui. Maybe try using ngx-auth-firebaseui, see if it works better.